# Check multiple values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to check the value of a range slider, and if that value is 1, add a class to an other element. The code below works well for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#range-slider").mousemove(function() {
    if (this.value == "1") {
      $('.other-element').addClass('is--active');
    } else {
      $('.other-element').removeClass('is--active');
    }
  });
});
```

However I'd like to do this for multiple values, but the below code does not work. So how can I achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#range-slider").mousemove(function() {
    if (this.value == "1", "2", "3", "4", "5") {
      $('.other-element').addClass('is--active');
    } else {
      $('.other-element').removeClass('is--active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your basic attempt needs each condition to be its own comparison - `this.value == 1 || this.value == 2 || this.vaue == 3`.   The cleanest is a switch using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the list of values includes `this.value` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#range-slider").mousemove(function() {
    if (["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].includes(this.value)) {
      $('.other-element').addClass('is--active');
    } else {
      $('.other-element').removeClass('is--active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: that's great thanks. Is there a way to shorten it even further, for example by saying "1 to 5" instead of "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" etc, because in some cases my list needs to include 30+ values.

Comment: Yes you can use `[...Array(30).keys()].map(x => (x+1).toString())` which will give you ['1', ... , '30']

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you want the action to happen for a certain range (10...20):

```js
$("#range-slider").on("input",function(){
  $(".other-element").toggleClass("active",this.value>9&&this.value<21)
})
```

```css
.active {background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="range-slider" min="0" max="50" value="5" step="1" />
<span class="other-element">in range</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you're looking to add a class to an element depending on the range slider's value, here's the code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#range-slider").on('mousemove', function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (value >= 1 && value <= 5) {
      $('.other-element').addClass('is-active').html(`Slider Active Value is: ${value}`);
    } else {
      $('.other-element').removeClass('is-active').html(`Slider Value is: ${value}`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.other-element {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.other-element.is-active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="range-slider" min="0" value="7" max="9">
<div class="other-element">value</div>
```

Comment: The range slider needs to update live, i.e. only as it is being dragged, not when the mouse is released, so the input event is inappropriate in this case.

Comment: If you want to dynamically add or remove a class as the slider is being dragged, you can use the 'mousemove' event. I've updated the code accordingly.